# What's the grammatical view?

Tags: phrase-usage

> It's she who had to leave her family.
>
> It's <strike>hers</strike> her who had to leave her family.

Are the sentences above correct?
If so, I want to know the difference, if there is.

Comment: Purists would ask ***Who** had to leave her family?*, and say that since the response ***Her** had to leave* isn't valid, this "proves" that your version must use ***she***. But many native speakers take little or no notice of this line of reasoning, particularly in [informal contexts](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+I+who%2CIt%27s+me+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20I%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20%27s%20me%20who%3B%2Cc0) (compare that "contracted" **it's** with the more formal version for **it is**).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Me agree that it don't matter anymore. Let's hear it for the impurists!

Comment: @P. E. Dant: ***Methinks** 'twas ever thus!* :)

Comment: Oh, you _would_ roll that one out! It's the equivalent of a fourth-best lead! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's she who had to leave her family. = grammatical, is/are are followed by subject pronouns. she, he, I, we, they.

It's hers=means some object belongs to her. It's called a possessive pronoun. The others are mine, hers,  his, theirs, ours, yours.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of question confuses even native speakers and leads to much argument.  As FumbleFingers mentions in his comment, you can try to rephrase the sentence as a question to get a clue which form of the pronoun to use:

> Who had to leave her family?  **She** did.

Using this technique, the answer would be:

> It is **she** who had to leave her family.

"She" sounds better in this case because it is the "subject" of the adjectival clause "who had to leave her family".  Without the clause it can be more natural to say, "It is *her*" -- although, arguably, "It is *she*" might still be more "correct" in perfectly *formal* English.

More examples:

> It is they/them who built the snowman.
>
> (Who built the snowman?  **They** did.) It is **they** who built the snowman.

.

> The sword shall be given to he/him who deserves it.
>
> (Who deserves it?  **He** does.)  The sword shall be given to **he** who deserves it.

.

> The sword shall be given to he/him.
>
> (Who is it given to?  It is given to **him**.)  The sword shall be given to **him**.

Again, see FumbleFingers' comment with the link to what people actually say.  Although this might be "correct":

> It is I/me who answered the phone.
>
> (Who answered the phone?  **I** did.)  It is **I** who answered the phone.

just as often, native speakers will say:

> "It's **me** who answered the phone."

Sorry I can't provide a more definite rule.  I recommend you pick which you prefer to use, and practice that form until it becomes second nature.